# Reduce datastore_v3.Next calls in Google App Engine when fetching objects (java), possible?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, optimization, jdo, datastore

I'm trying to optimize code that reads objects from Google's datastore. Using Java and JDO, here is my code:

```
List<Article> articles = (List<Article>) query.execute(articleId);
List<Article> detatchedArticles = (List<Article>) pm.detachCopyAll(articles);
```

When I look at the appstats logs, this results in:

```
datastore_v3.RunQuery   11ms (195ms api)
datastore_v3.Next   15ms (183ms api)
datastore_v3.Next   11ms (183ms api)
datastore_v3.Next   4ms (183ms api)
```

So, my question is; can I tweak somehow (JDO settings, other settings) how many objects that are fetched from the datastore per datastore_v2.Next?

I'm trying to win some API megacycles. Or, a lot, if what I want is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not already doing so, I would suggest using memcache. Depending on your entities, you could simply enable this in the jdoconfig.xml. Here's a short howto: http://ukena.de/content/enabling-jdo-caching-google-app-engine. Note that if you are using embedded entities, you will have to handle memcache manually due to some bug in GAE's  JDO implementation.

Comment: I started to write an own memcache implementation when I arrived at the office today, thus my entities were prepared for serialization when I read your answer. Enabling memcache as you described made a huge impact and the application runs fine. There are more RPCs now but each memcache.Get (which does the work instead of datastore_v3.Next) needs only 2ms. Maybe there are some room for tweaking lateron if I need to. Many thanks, this saves money!

Comment: A question though, do you know wether the 1.1.1 version of datanucleus cache is the best/latest to use with GAE? A bit unsure about their versions and what GAE uses.

Comment: I assumed that you have to use datanucleus-cache 1.x because GAE still uses datanucleus 1.x. Also, this is what seemed to be implied in datanuecleus's second comment to my answer overthere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061058/need-help-in-deciding-java-framework-libraries/6078172#comment-7045928

Comment: From what I see using Appstats, memcache reduces costs but actually increases the number of RPC and therefore the delay. I'm resorting to not using memcache in order to speed up server responses. It's such a slow dog the datastore